# Program doesn't print result until I type exit

Tags: c

i'm recently start to learning C because i start a course in my university. In one of my lesson I need to write a program that converts a number of in ms to days, hours, minutes, second and milliseconds.
I use this source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
long int time_ms;
int d, h, m, s, ms;
printf("insert the value in ms: \n");
scanf("%ld\n", &time_ms);

d = time_ms/(24*60*60*1000); //ms in a day
time_ms = time_ms%(24*60*60*1000); //reminder in ms

h = time_ms/(60*60*1000);
time_ms = time_ms%(60*60*1000);

m = time_ms/(60*1000);
time_ms = time_ms%(60*1000);

s = (time_ms/1000);
ms = time_ms%1000;

printf("%d d %d h %d m %d s %d ms\n",
         d,   h,   m,   s,   ms);
}
```

i compling it, and it work, but after i insert the number of milliseconds the shell of MacOs (were i'm working) doesn't print anything until i type "exit". what do i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made one of the classic mistakes: you used `scanf`.  There are a whole bunch of reasons not to use `scanf` *ever*, but right now the important reason is that `scanf("%d\n")` is going to *keep trying to read input* after the number, until it receives either EOF or something that isn't whitespace.

What you want to do instead is use `fgets`, which will read one entire line of input no matter what its contents are, and then `sscanf` to parse the number.  When you start writing more sophisticated programs you'll discover that even `sscanf` is troublesome and it's better to use lower-level functions like `strtol` and `strsep`, but for a classroom exercise like this `sscanf` is fine.

Comment: ok thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem:

```
scanf("%ld\n", &time_ms);
```

You have a `\n` in your sequence.  That means that after entering a number and pressing enter, `scanf` reads the number, then reads the newline, then is waiting for something that isn't a newline before returning.

Remove the newline character from the format string:

```
scanf("%ld", &time_ms);
```

Comment: That is going to lead OP headlong into the _other_ canonical scanf headache, where it leaves the trailing newline on the input buffer and the _next_ read misbehaves.  Better you should recommend `fgets` + `sscanf` or `strtol`.

Comment: ok thankyou dbush i resolved removin "\n" from scan. i will learn next in the course the other function. thank you